# How to forces 3 buttons to display in the same row evenly on all screensize?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons display in a row. I hate when I view it on the smaller screen, it forces the 3rd one to go into the new line.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent it by using width in `%` ? `33.333%` (since there're 3.)

I've tried that locally, and it does not seem to work.

```
<h1>

    <a href="/norden/create/poop" class="btn btn-md btn-warning"> poop <img class="logIcon" src="/assets/be/img/norden/poop.png" /> </a> 

    <a href="/norden/create/pee" class="btn btn-md btn-info"> pee <img class="logIcon" src="/assets/be/img/norden/pee.png" /> </a> 

    <a href="/norden/create/feed" class="btn btn-md btn-success"> feed <img class="logIcon" src="/assets/be/img/norden/feed.png" /> </a>


</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to the h1 add these styles

```css
/*your proper h1 selector*/ {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;  /* or space-around or space-evenly depending on your preference */
}
```

If you want it to wrap on very small screens add a `flex-wrap: wrap;` as well